# Bitwise structure programming in C

Tags: c, bit-fields

How does this work?

```
struct {
    int a : 21;
    int b : 11;
};
```

Are a and b two separate int variables or the same variable using different bit fields?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are two separate variables in the `struct`, one named `a` and one named `b`. However, they're sized so that `a` should have 21 bits and `b` should have 11 bits. Accessing one variable and manipulating it won't affect the other variable.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. So essentially both are 32 bit ints, but only 21 bits of a is used and 11 bits of b is used keeping other bits unutilized? Or does the compiler optimize this in some way? One could prefer using one 32 bit variable and splitting it into 21:11 bit fields...

Comment: @AbhinavChoudhury: Yes, the other bits will be unused.  The same thing happens even without bit fields, consider the declaration `struct s { int x; char y; };` which uses 8 bytes on most systems.

Comment: @AbhinavChoudhury They are 2 "32 bit" (or 16 bit, platform dependent) ints simply because of the way the memory is handeled by the system. If you declare int a:5, the CPU will also store this variable is the 32 bit (could be 16 bit depending on the system), because it is an integer and integers occupy a certain size in memory (again platform dependent, on my system and int is of size 2 Bytes but this not necessarly the case on yours). The `:21` and `:11` in your case simply limit the maximum value that you can assign to this variable.

Comment: BTW. If you want to store them in the same 32 bit register you could do sth like this (considering the fact int is 4 Bytes long) :
`int ab=a<<11+b`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: On what basis do you assert that two 32-bit entities will be used, with excess bits unused, rather than `a` and `b` being packed into one 32-bit entity? The C standard requires that successive fields be packed into whatever unit the implementation is using, if they fit completely. (If they do not fit, the standard permits either packing with a field partly in one unit and partly in the next or leaving bits unused.)

Answer (score 2):

It's not completely clear what you mean by 'variables' here. If you mean piece of memory you can take address of, then the bitfields do not fit the description as they are part of an 'addressable storage unit'. If by 'variable' you mean "set of bits that I can store some value in", then both a and b look like any other field in a structure.

Enough semantic nit-picking, though. Let's go to the source:

ch 6.7.2.1 in  [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) says:

> 10 An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large
>   enough to hold a bit- ﬁeld. If enough space remains, a bit-ﬁeld that
>   immediately follows another bit-ﬁeld in a structure shall be packed
>   into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufﬁcient space remains,
>   whether a bit-ﬁeld that does not ﬁt is put into the next unit or
>   overlaps adjacent units is implementation-deﬁned. The order of
>   allocation of bit-ﬁelds within a unit (high-order to low-order or
>   low-order to high-order) is implementation-deﬁned. The alignment of
>   the addressable storage unit is unspeciﬁed.

So, depending on "addressable storage unit" compiler picks, your a and b may end up in different 'storage units', depending on compiler specifics.

Comment: To be quite pedantic, the things in the C standard are “clauses”, not “chapters” (in regard to your abbreviation “ch”).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the system architecture as to how it's implemented. If you take a more straightforward example:

```
struct x {
  uint8_t a : 2;
  uint8_t b : 3;
};
```

Here it's possible that `a` and `b` will share the same byte of memory, for example: xxxb bbaa (where x is unused).

I believe that the semantics for alignment and packing are undefined - it's best to try it out! And watch out for different hardware (maybe even compilers) if you're doing a multi-platform project.

```
struct x s;
s.a = 3;
s.b = 5;
printf("0x%02X\n", *((char*)&s) );
```

The output might be any of `0x03`, `0x05`, `0x16` or even `0x25`.

I'd expect to see `0x16`...

In my opinion, when transmitting a bitfield, you should ALWAYS build a known state by hand.

```
uint8_t buf[];
buf[x] = 0;
buf[x] |= (s.a) & 0x03;
buf[x] |= (s.b << 2) & 0x1C;
```